# Show shared files google drive api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-drive-api

I have a code that shows files that has been shared with me.

I want to see the files that has been shared by me.

```
function getFiles(){
    var query = "";
    if (ifShowSharedFiles()) {
        $(".button-opt").hide();
        query = (FOLDER_ID == "root") ? "trashed=false and sharedWithMe" : "trashed=false and '" + FOLDER_ID + "' in parents";
        if (FOLDER_ID != "root" && FOLDER_PERMISSION == "true") {
            $(".button-opt").show();
        }
    }else{
        $(".button-opt").show();
        query = "trashed=false and '" + FOLDER_ID + "' in parents";
    }
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({
        'maxResults': NO_OF_FILES,
        'q': query
    });
```

is the google api able to show the files that I shared.

I searched 2 days for answer. (Don't understand how it's possible to not find an answer to this question)

I don't know in what I have to change `sharedWithMe`

EDIT: What I want to know is wich files I shared with others.
Now it shows files that has been shared with me by others.

Comment: @namazaG , have you found the solution ? I'm facing the same problem now.

Answer (score 0):

you can see all shared files with q = not 'me' in owners. add this parameter such as you are not owner means these files are shared.

Comment: What i need is a list of files that I have Shared.
now it shows files that has been shared with me by other i need files that has been shared TO others by me

Answer (score 0):

@anshuVersatile is correct. You can use the parameter `q` to query string for searching files. You can search or filter files with the [`files.list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list) method of the Drive API. Add attribute of the fil that is searched. Check the fields available [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters)